# CollapsingToolbarLayout content overlap to toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have problem in using CollapsingToolbarLayout. Actually I want to stick the toolbar but the content below it is in parallax mode, so that it can hide on scroll up and view when scroll down. It is happening but my issue is that the content in parallax linearlayout overlap to the tool bar.

I have tried many options add the toolbar and linearlayout in another linear layout with orientation vertical but then collapsingToolbarLayout stop working.

I have also tried by adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" but its also not solving my problem. My layout code is as given below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Email"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="70dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffe5e5e5"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/placeCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="General"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray_transparent3">
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="Model: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewModel"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="SKU: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewSKU"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="EAN: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewEAN"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="UPC: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewUPC"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="Manufacturer: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewManufacturer"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="Price: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="Quantity: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewQuantity"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="Status: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="Stock availability: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewStockAvailability"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text="Total Ordered: "/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewTotalOrdered"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/placeCardDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray_transparent3">
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewHtmlDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text=""
                    />


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And the output is like the attached file:
[image]

I need to that content "Email" will start from bottom of the tool bar with collapse effect.

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in onCreate(), this will not overlap the titles

```
  final CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbar);
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBar);

    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (verticalOffset == 0 || verticalOffset <= toolbarInPerspectiveActivity.getHeight() && !toolbarInPerspectiveActivity.getTitle().equals(mCollapsedTitle)) {
                mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(mExpandedTitle);
            } else if (!toolbarInPerspectiveActivity.getTitle().equals(mExpandedTitle)) {
                mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(mCollapsedTitle);
            }
        }
    });
```

And set expanded title and collapsed title where you setting toolbar title.